# Total Beginner: Python 3.4 spot the syntax error

Tags: python-3.4

When running the following code, I get an error as follows:

```
for (x in List[0] and y in range(0,11)):
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am very new to Python programming. When I try to run the iteration at the top I get the above error-message.

Could someone please kindly explain which part of the syntax is invalid?

The tiny arrow underneath seems to point to the colon.

Many thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `a in A and b in B`? Are you trying to go through every value in `List[0]` and then `range(0, 11)`, or are you trying to go through all pairs of `List[0]` and `range(0, 11)`?

Comment: @JamesSmith Hi James, thanks for your reply, I am trying to go through all pairs of List[0] and range(0,11).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Syntax Error**: The brackets are not necessary; use the following:

```
for x in List[0] and y in range(0, 11): ...
```

**More Problems** Although as in my comment, this won't necessarily work.

**Merging the Arrays**:
If you are trying to go through all values in `List[0]` and then in `range(0, 11)`, do the following:

```
for x in (List[0] + range(0, 11)): ...
```

**No Duplicates**:
Or, if you want no duplicates, and ordering does not matter, use this:

```
for x in list(set(List[0] + range(0, 11))): ...
```

**Going through all pairs**:
Or, if you are trying to go through all pairs consisting of a value in `List[0]` and a value in `range(0, 11)`, use the following:

```
for x in List[0]:
    for y in range(0, 11):
        ...
```

Comment: There are some bracktes missing in example two and three.